# Failed to iterate over selected rows

Tags: php, mysql

The code is supposed to get a row at each loop and build `td` elements for each data piece. However, it only gets some rows while missing others even though all rows were selected:

```
$query = "select * from category";
$ret = mysql_query($query, $conn);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($ret)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($rows as $val) {
    echo "<td>{$val}</td>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Wheres the rest of the code/table?

Comment: You are doing it wrong: you are using the [deprecated mysql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)!

Comment: please show the problem in detail , like what are u getting as output , where is the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc returns an associative array. To display each returned row, do something like this (taken directly from the php.net page for mysql_fetch_assoc

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row["userid"];
echo $row["fullname"];
echo $row["userstatus"];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the curly braces like this:

```
echo "<td>$val</td>";
```

Beside you didn't close the `<tr>` tag. So you should do this:

```
$query = "select * from category";
$ret = mysql_query($query, $conn);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($ret)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($rows as $val) {
    echo "<td>$val</td>";
  }
  echo"</tr>";
}
```

Now like Jack Albright said you should consider various columns of your table to display specific data. Upon that the `while()` is already a look, I think you don't need to add any `foreach()` inside. SO your final code should look like this:

```
$query = "select * from category";
$ret = mysql_query($query, $conn);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($ret)) {
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$rows['columnName']</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```